# Animation out of memory error

Tags: android, performance, android-animation, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a app just like talking tom cat.I am using drawable animation to load image and animate for different sequences.After some animations application force closed.
I already tried reducing the image size and images bit depth.Any one have any idea how to avoid this error other than calling system.gc

please help

Comment: If an OutOfMemoryError is thrown then normally a gc wouldn't help either. Show the relevant code, this more sounds like a memory leak

Comment: The `UIViewAnimation` tag is about iOS (tag removed).

Answer (score 0):

MP4 files and `MediaPlayer` should make it easier.

Comment: Already tried using videos with different resolutions for different screen sizes.In some phones video is getting slower some time.

Comment: Sounds like memory leak. Try writing amount of free memory to `Log` in critical places and analysing it.